# call to google maps not valid when changing pages - jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use google maps within my jquery mobile app.
It worked nicely within a single html page app (with different pages marked by data-role=page)
but when I try to use it in a multy-page setup, changing pages with

```
    $.mobile.changePage(('location.html'),{
        ajax:false
    });
```

i get undefined is not a function. refreshing the page makes it work.
so i guess my question is where should i put the call to google api?
I tried adding it to  the index page's head, on the "location.html" page's head, and inside its body.

Comment: `ajax:false` isn't an argument of `changePage`. if you want to navigate programmatically with ajax off, use `window.location.href=location.html`. if you want to force reload a page but using ajax `$.mobile.changePage('location.html', { reloadPage: true });`

Comment: that does not seem to help.

Comment: Define *that*. What and how have you tried them?